# Android graphical layout has a default actionbar shown in some cases

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, graphical-layout-editor

In the xml graphical layout of my android application there is a actionbar shown in one of my android studio projects and not in others. Out of curiosity i would like to know the reason behind this. I don't see any changes in the themes of either of the layouts and activities.

Something like this is shown :
[image]

PS: the part above the dotted line is the actionbar. I want it removed somehow. It's not there in any of my other Android Studio projects.

Comment: Please post the code of a project that shows the action bar and one that doesn´t. That are a lot of ways to hiding the ActionBar, are impossible to say where you are changing it without the code.

Comment: This is just an empty layout in my project. Creating another empty layout in another project doesn't show this actionbar by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and add AppTheme.NoAction to your activity in Manifest

Comment: The AppTheme.AppBarOverlay and AppTheme.PopupOverlay are totally unnecessary for the example.

Comment: Yes it is. It was one of my old codes, which had that. Edited it. :)